# CSS image with div border

Tags: css

This may be hard to describe with english. I want an image (50x50 with a `margin-right:20px`) and then next to that image (to the right) i want a div (with border) to go to the end of the container.  The container can be any size (so static values would be... well yuck).  I was wondering if there was a way to do this without javascript.

So if i did something like this:

```
.img { width:50px; margin-right:20px }
.content { height:30px; line-height:30px; padding:10px 0; border:1px solid #272727 }
```

And i want that code to look like something like this:

```
<div id='some-global-container-that-is-a-resizable-length'>
    <div class='img'>
        <img src='myimage.png'>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
        here is some content i want to be displayed from my server
    </div>
</div>
```

If i accidentally i forgot to close a tag or something its ok, the real code was not made in the stack overflow wysiwyg... This is a css question.. K thx!

---

I forgot to say this...
    If i try to do the .img with `float:left` it will appear "within" the other div... which is not what i want and `display:inline` will make the div (with border) appear below the image div.

Comment: So, you want: `[img] [...............content...............]` ?

Comment: precisely!  (That was so much easier than i made it)

Comment: and sometimes the image can be of different sizes (i could just do some margin-left and float in the image, but i was wondering if there was a less "hacky" way. soo more like `[img] [......content....] <br/> [..img..] [...content...]`

Comment: To make them both resizeable it would be easiest to just have the server generate numbers based on the width of the image and add them as inline styles. Two horizontally auto resizing sections next to each other can be really hard to do while still maintaining cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <img />
    <div class='text'>
        content...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container{
    overflow:hidden;
}

img{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ffa;
    float:left;
}

.text{
    margin-left:70px;
}
```

JSFIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/qy3yy/

Comment: This is actually what i did except for one difference.  Since img's can be different sizes (of my choosing) (which sucks because i wanted a dynamic solution) i just did .text.img50 (then made the margin left 70px)  I wish there was a non javascript dynamic solution that does not require static values.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS should take care of your layout.

```
.img{width:50px; float: left; clear: none;}
.content{width: auto; margin-left: 50px; float: none;}
```

You can add other styles as needed. The image will not appear as if inside the DIV. :)

Comment: Your method is a bit more complicated than the one below.

Comment: complicated? - BTW, if you're not a table hater (i happen to be btw), a table can make this work.